# React Native android builds very slow ( > 3min)

Tags: android, build, react-native

I am experiencing very slow build times and quite poor debugging performance on android in my React Native app, whereas before the builds were breezing by in around 30 seconds, and running the app with remote debugging enabled was somewhat manageable. I am not sure what I changed to cause this, but here are some of the symptoms I'm seeing when running `react-native run-android`:

**1) All dependencies are being installed as separate APK's on my device**

For every dependency in my app, I see the following in the build logs:

```
...
Installing APK 'react-native-toast-debug-androidTest.apk' on 'Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920 - 6.0' for react-native-toast:debugAndroidTest
Installed on 1 device.
...
Installing APK 'react-native-vector-icons-debug-androidTest.apk' on 'Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920 - 6.0' for react-native-vector-icons:debugAndroidTest
Installed on 1 device.
...
```

[image]

**2) Wrong build tools version is used**

This warning might be caused by the build tools versions specified in each of the dependency projects, but:

```
Running dex in-process requires build tools 23.0.2.
For faster builds update this project to use the latest build tools.
```

When in my build.gradle I have defined the build tools version as 23.2.3

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.2.3"
```

**3) Adb invocation fails**

At the end of the build, this message is displayed and the app is not automatically launched on my device:

```
adb invocation failed. Do you have adb in your PATH?
```

Even though I have adb in my PATH (.bashrc)

```
export PATH="/Users/Juuso/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
```

...and I am able to run adb commands in my project directory

Answer (score 1):

if you ever add buildTypes or productFlavors in android/app/build.gradle like me.

do not run `react-native run-android`

use `react-native run-anroid --variant [flavorBuildType]` instead

flavorBuildType could be, any of following.

1. debug
2. release
3. flavor1Debug
4. flavor2Release

Comment: Just note a bit of spelling mistake - `react-native run-android --variant [flavorBuildType]`